# Using Bootstrap Grid System to display Vertically stacked data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to use AngularJS, and Bootstrap to create a way to display hierarchical data. With the help of you fellow stackoverflowers, I build a nice sliding effect for displaying categories and subcategories using bootstrap badges.

Here is a PLNKR showing how nicely it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/5I1pU0TZo6AjHJTbBuG9

In that example we have two main categories: fruit and vegetables

The problems begin when I try to expand the number of categories out. In the real world I will probably have ~100 main categories that users will want to use to try and find more specific sub-categories.

Let me first describe the ultimate way I would like the categories to be displayed, and how they interact when clicked. The categories should display in vertical order like below:

```
category-1          category-26          category-51        category-76
category-2          category-27          category-52        category-77
category-3          category-28          category-53        category-78
    .                   .                    .                  .
    .                   .                    .                  .
    .                   .                    .                  .
category-24          category-49          category-74       category-99
category-25          category-50          category-75       category-100
```

When, say, category-3 three is clicked, below it opens up the subcategories for it in the first column. Any overflow should be divided amongst the other columns.

Ie. if there are 10, say, sub-categories opened up by clicking category-3, then 3 extra rows should be added to the grid, with categories shifting from the first column across to the second column and so on until everything looks balanced.

I would also like the number of columns that are used to display the data to be responsive... ie. 2 columns on phones, 3 on tablet, 4 on desktop, say.

Now, I've set up a very ugly looking PLNKR which shows my first extremely disappointing version: http://plnkr.co/edit/jeVxDKp268WlQWzhSQU8

In it I used the bootstrap col-xs-6, and col-md-3 classes to help put the data in a grid. It essentially does exactly what I want - EXCEPT it stacks all the elements horizontally and not vertically...

To be explicit, the categories are displaying in the following unhelpful fashion:

```
category-1          category-2          category-3        category-4
category-5          category-6          category-7        category-8
category-9          category-10         category-11       category-12
    .                   .                    .                  .
    .                   .                    .                  .
    .                   .                    .                  .
category-93         category-94         category-95       category-96
category-97         category-98         category-99       category-100
```

And to make matters worse, when you click on a category, the sub-categories are also displayed in this manner, so all indentation applied to the sub-categories to help the user visualise how far down the tree one is, only serves to baffle!

Here is the html I've used to display the categories:

```
<ul id="categoriesUnorderedList">
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories"
        ng-show="category.category_show"
        class="badge-slider col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <span ng-click="categoryClicked(category)"
            class="badge {{ getBadgeClassName(category.category_type) }}"
            ng-style="getIndent(category)">
            {{category.category_name}}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there another approach you know works? Is the bootstrap grid-system never going to work for this type of data? All help much appreciated....

Comment: for modern browsers could use css3 columns instead of using float

Comment: Cheers charlietfl... i've posted an answer using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per charlietfl suggested, I used css3 columns to do the trick.

The css code needed was:

```
ul {
-webkit-column-width: 200px;
-moz-column-width: 200px;
-o-column-width: 200px;
column-width: 200px;

-webkit-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-count: 4;
-o-column-count: 4;
column-count: 4;

list-style-type: none;
```

}

I also needed to remove the bootstrap grid stuff from the html:

```
<ul id="categoriesUnorderedList">
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-show="category.category_show" class="badge-slider">
        <span ng-click="categoryClicked(category)" class="badge {{ getBadgeClassName(category.category_type) }}" ng-style="getIndent(category)">
          {{category.category_name}}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the working PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/blKAUiUT2Ql0HGMCrJb1

Answer (score -1):

The above solution is working only if column width is 200px. For same number of columns and column width 600px, it's not working.